# android media player service with timer

Tags: android, audio, service

I have not been able to find a solid answer for this anywhere so i was hoping that someone could just help me with some code. I have an app that has the user pick a time from a string and then hit the play button. The song then plays for that length of time and then stops. The problem is that I have this set in an activity, not a service. I have found examples of how to use a service for playing and stopping a song but I have not found out how to do this and still be able to have the user be able to select the time of the song. Could someone please give me a snip of code that would show me how to be able to implement the service without losing the ability to pick the length of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use this to set the time of how long the media player will play

```
                new CountDownTimer(1000 * lengthOfTime, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {

                        if(yourMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                            yourMediaPlayer.stop();
                            yourMediaPlayer.release();
                       }
                           }
                    }
                    }.start();
```

Create your service and call it using

```
Intent it = new Intent();
it.setAction("your.package.name.whatEverYourServiceName");
startService(it);
```

Then add this on your manifest:

```
 <service
        android:name="your.package.name.whatEverYourServiceName"
        android:label="Your Service Homie"
        android:process=":my_process" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="your.package.name.whatEverYourServiceName" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

here is the service sample:

```
public class whatEverYourServiceName extends Service{


@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){
super.onStart(intent, startId);

//Add your code here mate

}


@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();

    //Add what do you want to do here when the service is stop like do a backflip

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}

}
```

If you are using an eclipse just press ctrl+shift+o to automatically import the packages.

Comment: I have it working to set the time, My issue is that I need the sound to be playing from a service instead of the activity and  Idont know how to do impliment the service

Comment: what goes in the service code or is it left empty after the class is created? and would it help you if I posted my main activity java class

Comment: Just add your media player and timer on your service and call `stopService(new Intent(whatEverYourServiceName.this,    whatEverYourServiceName.class));` to stop the service.

Comment: so far you have been a big help so please forgive my billion questions, I really dont know how to do the service class, thats my main question.

Comment: so in my main activity I should replace the Playsound(R.id.shipsound) with the call for the service, and I should not change anything else in my main activity?